# Reading classic asp.net request http headers in c#

Tags: .net, asp-classic, com

Does anyone know how to read all http headers from classic asp request object in c# into a string? My code is this:

```
ASPTypeLibrary.IRequestDictionary dictionary = request.ServerVariables;
object headers = dictionary["ALL_HTTP"];
return (string)headers;
```

The last line fails.

Please help! GRR COM!

Comment: because you're casting a dictionary to a string.. of course it's going to fail

Comment: @Alex any idea what the type of `headers` should be then? in the debugger there is no type information.

Comment: @Alex I would have thought if I did `object headers = dictionary` then I would get a dictionary `object headers = dictionary["ALL_HTTP"]` should give the value given the key "ALL_HTTP", but thanks anyway.

Comment: What, from the headers, are you trying to return? They are Key value pairs... the last line fails because you are trying to cast the key value pair to a string

Comment: Which one is it? Class ASP or ASP.NET?  Two very different animals!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get the value out by doing the following:

```
string variableValue = string.Empty;
foreach (string item in ((IEnumerable)request["ALL_HTTP"])) variableValue = item;
```